# How to allow SSH access for a system user on Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ssh

I have created a new system user on my DigitalOcean Droplet but I cannot SSH into my server through PuTTY as this user. I have added the public key for this user into the authorized_keys file in the root/.ssh directory and configured PuTTY to use the private key but it continues to fail. The user was created with a home directory e.g. /home/ben

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’ve edited the question now, I can’t do the debug right now but hopefully it helps. The ~ is the root directory.

Comment: Unless you have specified otherwise via the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, a user's `authorized_keys` file is expected to be in that user's `$HOME/.ssh`, and both the file and the containing directory permissions must be restricted as discussed here [SSH and home directory permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions). IIRC the user must also have a valid login shell (which system users often do not, by default).

Comment: Are you using `ssh root@server.domain.address` or `ssh ben@server.domain.address`? It may be entered differently in PuTTy.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks for the help guys.